# Using makefile variables in C

Tags: c, file, makefile

I need to read a file in a C program and I do not want to hardcode the path to that file. I want to provide that path as a Make variable and then use it in C prog.

```
file name is xyz.txt and I want to do something like this in C prog:
fopen ("PATH/xyz.txt", "r"); 
here PATH is specified in make command that compiles this file.
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Setting `PATH` at compile time via a make is no different than hard-coding it; it still is predefined in the executable. You're better off just having it accept a command-line parameter or reading from an environmental variable at runtime.

Comment: @Ken: I believe, its better than hard-coding. The location of the file differs with the consumer of this program. So I need a way such that I do not need to modify/change the interface of the program. For example, for consumer1 - its makefile sets PATH = /a/b/c and for comsumer2- its makefile sets PATH = /d/e/f/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This probably *should* be done with a command line parameter but, if you must do it within the makefile, you can use the following:

```
$ cat makefile
qq: myprog.c makefile
    gcc -DMYSTRING='"hello"' -o myprog -Wall myprog.c


$ cat myprog.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf ("[%s]\n", MYSTRING);
    return 0;
}
```

The `-D` specifies a compile-time `#define` which sets `MYSTRING` to `"hello"`.

Then, when you use `MYSTRING` in the code, it's turned into the string. In that sample code, I simply pass it to `printf` but you could equally well pass it to `fopen` as per your requirement.

When you run that executable, the output is:

```
[hello]
```

This is little different to simply hard-coding the value in the source code - you will have to recompile if you ever want the string to change (which is why I suggested a command line parameter in the first paragraph).

Comment: Cool...thanks much. On the other hand, I thought, I could set PATH as an env variable inside Makefile and use it with getenv() ??

Comment: @hari - no, that wouldn't work. The Makefile determines compile time parameters, but `getenv()` works at run time.

Answer (score 3):

You'd want to handle this via string concatenation:

makefile:

```
PATH = "/usr/bin/"

program: # whatever
    $CC /DPATH=$(PATH)
```

Then in your C file you'd have something like:

```
fopen(PATH "xyz.txt", "r");
```

The compiler will concatenate the strings together into a single string during preprocessing.

Answer (score 2):

If you are gcc or, any similar compiler, you can use the `-D` flag, documented [inside the manpage.](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc)

To give a quick overview, you can do `gcc -DSYMBOL=1`, and this would result in the compiler adding this to the code:

```
#define SYMBOL 1
```

So, in your makefile, you can set a make variable, and then pass it to the gcc command line options.

Answer (score 0):

I am beginner to makefile, and I finally got a better way to pass variables from `makefile` to `#define`, and won't be affect by Escape.

##1. pass a string

you can use following code

```
-D STRING_SAMPLE='"string sample"'
```

is equal to

```
#define STRING_SAMPLE "string sample"
```

##2. pass a int or char

you can use following code

```
-D CHAR_SAMPLE="'\n'"
```

is equal to

```
#define CHAR_SAMPLE '\n'
```

##3. SampleCode

```
# makefile sample
CC = gcc
CCFLAGS = -Wall -O

# run `make test` in terminal
test:main run clean

run:
    @./main.e

main: 
    @$(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -c main.c -D STRING_SAMPLE='"string sample"' -D CHAR_SAMPLE="'\n'" -o main.o 
    @$(CC)  main.o -o main.e

.PHONY:clean
clean:
    @rm *.e
    @rm *.o
```

and main.c

```
//sample code in C
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"
int main(void){
    puts("start test char");
    printf("value(hex)==%.2x\n",CHAR_SAMPLE);
    puts("end test char");
    int i;
    puts("start test string");
    for (i=0; i< sizeof(STRING_SAMPLE); i++) {
        printf("value%d(hex)==<%.2x>\n",i,STRING_SAMPLE[i]);
    }
    puts("end test string");
}
```